# Using SSO (getAccessTokenAsync) in an Outlook add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to get the new [SSO functionality](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) working in an Outlook add-in but `getAccessTokenAsync` returns the following error:

```
Code: 5001
Message: An internal error has occurred.
Name: Internal Error
```

The manifest looks as follows:

```xml
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    ...
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>{App-ID}</Id>
      <Resource>api://myDomain.com/OutlookAddIn/Home.html/{App-ID}<Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
```

I am currently using Office version 1708. Any ideas? Does it even work yet with Outlook?

The sample for PowerPoint ([Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO)) is working for me.

Comment: Could you confirm the build number for Outlook and whether you are using click to run? Note that for the current sample on https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO, the prerequisite is Office 2016, Version 1710, build 16.0.8605.1000 Click-to-Run, or later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The build number is 16.0.8431.2079 and yes I am using Click-to-Run.The PowerPoint sample is working with my version of Office. Do I need a newer one for Outlook?

Comment: That build, with click-to-run, should work for the basic flow. Another thing to check, when you register the AAD app, do you have the 'profile' scope included? After you add profile, please remember to do the admin consent again.

Comment: Yes, the 'profile' scope is included. I am using the same AAD app I used with the PowerPoint example except that I've changed the Redirect URL and Application-ID-URI for this one.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Unfortunately, our better error codes are in later build, so it's harder to figure this out. 2 things to check: is your email a consumer or a business (o365 account)? Consumer account support is not yet ready in Outlook. For business account, is modern auth enabled? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx  Another thing that might help is to capture a network trace (eg fiddler) and see if we see errors there.

Comment: The account is a Office 365 account and modern auth is also enabled. I tried to capture the network traffic but can't find any requests to login.microsoftonline.com or login.windows.net. Is there another thing to search for?

Comment: You are looking for the right things from network trace. The build you have is the earliest that we have the basic SSO flow enabled, and we have had fixes, including better error info, on the later builds. I don't have other debugging ideas. Is it possible for you to update to a newer build? One thing I haven't answered is that while a large part of the logic is shared with the rest of Office, there is Outlook specific logic (to use the correct Outlook account) for the flow to work.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I'll probably wait until I get a newer build of Office then.